# importance of <ApplicationName>_prefix.pch file

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios

What is the importance of importance of _prefix.pch file?

Comment: Do you want to know if it's important or what it does?

Comment: "importance of importance of"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conceptually, it's included at the top of every translation unit (i.e. every compiled C, C++, Objective-C, or Objective-C++ file.) So you can force every file in your project to include a particular macro by adding this to your .pch file:

```
#if !defined(MY_MACRO)
    #define MY_MACRO (12345)
#endif /* !defined(MY_MACRO) */
```

And then `MY_MACRO` is always available. It's also commonly used to import framework headers so you don't have to run around typing `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` in every file.